# Коррекция даты для записи в БД mysql с учетом часового пояса.

Tags: часовые-пояса, php, mysql

Привет всем. Подскажите, люди добрые, где можно получить информацию о настройках часовых поясов для БД mysql. У меня в комментариях пользователей автоматически фиксируется дата поста. Насколько я понимаю, эту дату нужно как-то корректировать с учетом географического местоположения пользователя.

Comment: Как правило дату записи поля в бд ставят относительно сервера. Для этого выберите тип поля TIMESTAMP и значение по умолчанию CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Цепляться к настрйокам времени пользователя не стоит, так как если вывод сообщений будете делать по дате добавления по убыванию от самых свежих, пользователь выставивший на своём компьютере к примеру 2050 год на ближайшие 36 лет попадёт в топ. И выгнать его оттуда получится только исправив запись в БД.

Comment: У меня так все и настроено, однако если я пишу с Украины, например, то дата поставится 17.00 - так и выведется на экран. А с России - это уже будет 19.00, но сервер установит все равно 17.00? 

Т.е. я увижу для себя правильное время, а пользователь из России, соответственно, неправильно относительно России время?

Comment: Пользователь из России увидит не неправильное время, а время по серверу. Можно в заголовок сайта добавить js скрипт часов на которых показваеть серверное время с припиской в каком часовом поясе находится сайт.

Попробуйте сделать фишку как здесь. У сообщений показывается не время создания коментария, а сколько прошло времени.

Comment: @terantul, неужели на ресурсах, где пишется фактическое время сообщений, это время регулируется javascript'ом???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php не имеет доступа к таким данным. Как правило строят примерно такую конструкцию:

На странице формы добавления коментария добавьте js код который вычилсяет часовой пояс посетителя
(тут подробнее о вычислении времени http://javascript.ru/Date/getTimezoneOffset ). 
Дальше вешаете на кнопку отправки формы действие онклик который запускает js функцию добавления поля hidden cо значением времени посетителя.

```
timeUserInput = "<input name=\"timeUser\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" + timeUser + "\" />"

document.getElementById("formCommentID").appendChild(timeUserInput);
```

В php коде который принимает данные ловим нашу переменную $_POST['timeUser']. Обязательно проверяем её на существование, так как если у посетителя отключён js в браузере то её не будет.

ЗЫ. Сори пришлось вставлять новый ответ так как не хватило лимита символов для ответа в коментариях.

Comment: о_О, пропал мой комментарий. Хорошо, пусть будет так, но на хэш-коде время более ранних вопросом стоит с конкретными часами и минутами. Это не фактическое время, а время относительно сервера?

Comment: @terantul, вы написали нерабочий код! Это же не jQuery! 
Так будет работать:

    timeUserInput = document.createElement('input');

Comment: В js не силён (. Подцепить время пользователя можно только через js . Насчёт ХешКода не скажу как реализовано.
Саму логику построения нужной функции написал выше. Какие нюансы возникают при привязке к времени посетителя также указал. Теперь уже Вам выбирать, стоит ли использовать эту схему.